# PHP webinterface to python backend for mail monitoring

Tags: php, python, web-applications, postfix-mta

After writing python scripts for a while now, I was planning on stepping up my game a bit and delve a bit deeper into real applications for my coding.

I have a mailcluster with several postfix-machines which aren't really accessible to anyone other than myself for monitoring; I want to make a website that allows other (non-root) users to view queue-sizes and maybe search the logs for certain data like bounces and all that jazz.

I was hoping to have a php-page (I'd have to get into PHP, but I like to learn so that's not an issue) which calls to a python-service which listens on each server so I can gather data on demand, however I'm getting a little swamped by all the information on the web about this topic and frankly I can't really find anything that really applies to what I'm trying to accomplish (as far as I can see, anyway). I hope the kind people of StackOverflow can help me by pointing me in the right direction.

Please note that I'm not looking for a solution that has this functionality. This is meant to be useful for my non-root co-workers as much as it's an exercise for me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an extra php-page for that. You can simply use a microwebframework and do it all in python.

I prefer:

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/

but this is also quite popular:

http://flask.pocoo.org/

However if you still want to use php you can use those frameworks to only build the backend as well.

Comment: I wouldn't mind going python-only, so I'll definitely check out your suggestions :)